# TSQL - how can I sum values except absolutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, gaps-and-islands

I would like to sum values in my table, except the ones that are absolute (field absolute, value = 1). If that's the case, the summing should reset. Example:

```
Date            Value      Absolute
1-1-2020        4          0    
1-2-2020        7          1    
1-3-2020        3          0
```

Regular SUM() would return (4+7+3=) 14. But in this example it should reset at value 7, which makes a sum of (7+3=) 10.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a window sum that resets everytime `absolute` is `1`. If so, you can do:

```
select t.*, sum(value) over(partition by grp order by date) sum_value
from (
    select t.*, sum(absolute) over(order by date) grp 
    from mytable t
) t
```

The subquery uses a window sum of `absolute` to define the groups, then the outer query performs the sums `value` over each group.